# Custom local npm module as dependency

Tags: json, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

I created a project using npm scripts in order to avoid the use of gulp. The thing is, my project has two scripts:

```
prepare.sh (uses wget to download some files and do mkdirs)
process.js (transform a json file into another overriding some keys)
package.json

{
"scripts": {
  "process": "./process.js",
  "prepare": "./prepare.sh $npm_package_config_source $npm_config_env",
  "config": "npm run prepare && npm run process"
},
"config": {
   "source": "https://myurl"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "fs": "0.0.1-security",
  "json-override": "^0.2.0"
}
```

}

So, if I want to apply the transform in this project I run `npm run config`, but I want this project to be part of another as a local module of a front-end project.

How can I set up my project? And when I add it as a dependency of my front project, how can I call the config script from the `package.json` of the front project?

Comment: You can add a bin object to your package.json which will result in files installed into the node_modules/.bin folder https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bin object to your package.json which will result in files installed into the node_modules/.bin folder docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

example

```
{
  "bin": {
    "process": "./process.js",
    "prepare": "./prepare.sh"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "config": "prepare && process"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "json-override": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Also since npm runs scripts with node_modules/.bin as part of the path you can simply call them by name only.  Just remember to add `#!/usr/bin/env node` to the top of process.js

Comment: I don't know how execute this :)  I've just updated my question to a real one aproach. I added my config section and two parameters that I use. One from the config part and another one from commands. Until now, I execute this using: npm run config --env=LOCAL. I want this project to be part as dependency of the front and to be executable also in the server to perform transformations on the fly. Is it possible to do this using the bin approach? And.. how I execute it?